# How to create an object JSON filter in JS/TS?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, filter

Here is the problem, I'm trying to create a filter based in an object JSON on the server side, the easiest example is youtube, I want a video with less than 4 minutes, at the first half of December 2022 that starts with the word "vlog". So the filter would be like this:

```
{
  "type": "video",
    "date": {
      "gte": "12-01-2022",
      "lt": "12-15-2022"
    },
    "searchValue":"vlog",
    "duration": {
      "lte": "240"
    }
}
```

But we all know that the main object has other variables like "order by" or "features".
So the question is, how to create this filter based in an object the best possible way?

What I tried to do was to get every record that I have on my DB and then match the filters that the client wanted but this consumes too much of our database and I know that is not the best way to do it.

Comment: I'd consider MongoDB as database, which can be easily filtered using JSON.

Comment: here we're using postgresql with knexdb